# Prove that $\cos(x)$ is identically zero using integration by parts

Tags: calculus, puzzle, integration

Consider $$\int\cos(t-x)\sin(x)dx,$$ where $t$ is a constant.

Evaluating the integral by parts, let
\begin{align}
u = \cos(t-x),\ dv = \sin(x), \\
du = \sin(t-x),\ v = -\cos(x),
\end{align}
so
$$
\int\cos(t-x)\sin(x)dx = -\cos(t-x)\cos(x) - \int\sin(t-x)\cdot-\cos(x)dx.
$$
Evaluating the integral on the right by parts again (with a slight abuse of notation),
\begin{align}
u = \sin(t-x),&\quad dv = -\cos(x), \\
du = -\cos(t-x),&\quad v = -\sin(x),
\end{align}
we get
\begin{align}
\int\cos(t-x)\sin(x)dx &= -\cos(t-x)\cos(x) - \left( -\sin(t-x)\sin(x)-\int\cos(t-x)\sin(x)dx\right) \\
&= -\cos(t-x)\cos(x) + \sin(t-x)\sin(x) + \int\cos(t-x)\sin(x)dx,
\end{align}
and subtracting the integral from both sides, we obtain the dazzling new identity
$$\sin(t-x)\sin(x)-\cos(t-x)\cos(x)=0$$
for all $t$ and $x$!

Pushing it further, the LHS expression is $-\cos(t)$, and as $t$ was just an arbitrary constant, this implies $\cos(x)$ is identically zero!

Now I obviously know something's wrong here. But what, and where? Where's the flaw in my reasoning?

**P.S.** I can evaluate the integral to get the proper answer lol. But this was rather interesting.

Comment: Argh I keep hitting enter too soon. Updating.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20cos(t-x)sin(x)dx&t=crmtb01

Comment: You've tried expanding out using the difference of two angles formula for the cosine?

Comment: Question's been updated thanks.

Comment: In your last step you say $=0$, but you should actually say "is constant".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard trigonometric identity says that
$$\sin(t-x)\sin(x)-\cos(t-x)\cos(x)$$
is equal to
$$
-\cos((t-x)+x)
$$
and that is $-\cos t$.  As a function of $x$, this is a constant, i.e. since there's no "$x$" in this expression, it doesn't change as $x$ changes.  Since the "dazzling new identity", if stated correctly, would say, not that the expression equals $0$, but that the expression is constant, it seems your derivation is correct.  Except that you wrote "$=0$" where you needed "$=\text{constant}$".

Comment: Ahaha oops. In the fun of the moment I completely forgot $+c$. So the great mystery was all because of that high-school mistake. `:P`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're working with *indefinite* integrals, so you have to be careful about arbitrary constants of integration. When using by-parts integration on indefinite integrals you're only guaranteed to get another antiderivative, not necessarily *the same* antiderivative as this example clearly demonstrates. Here it turns out that the LHS is the original antiderivative, and the RHS is the same antiderivative plus $-\cos t$ (which is a constant with respect to $x$).

If you worked the same example out with *definite* integration instead, you would wind up with
$$0=-\cos( t)\big|_{x=a}^{x=b}=-\cos t-(-\cos t)=0. $$

Comment: Equally good answer! Thanks :)